# How do you make one div vertically scrollable and the other not with two inline-block divs?

Tags: html, css

I have two inline-block divs on my website, and I would like to make the right-hand div acquire a vertical scrollbar when the browser resizes vertically, but *only* the right-hand div (not the left-hand one).

I created a much simplified version of my website on jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/nky2buhr/7/

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>

#container {
  height: 300px;
}

#left {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

#right {
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

If you resize the result window vertically, you'll see that a scrollbar appears, but the scrollbar appears for the entire document and not just the right-hand div. What I would like to see happen is for a vertical scrollbar to appear *only* for the right-hand div.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: but you need some overflow inside the right div to have a scroll

Comment: @TemaniAfif I want the right div to scroll when the browser resizes vertically (or in the case on jsfiddle, when the result window shrinks vertically). Does that make sense? The browser resizing should cause the scroll.

Comment: yes but a scroll appear only if we have overflow, and your div is empty. So to scroll what?

Comment: @TemaniAfif But theoretically speaking, doesn't a scroll appear when the browser resizes? In my jsfiddle, if you resize the result window vertically you can induce a scrollbar to appear - even though the divs are empty. After all, the divs might be empty but they have a height and a width.

Comment: no, the scroll appear on the body because there is a content inside it and this content is your div with a fixed height ... so if the height of body is smaller than the height of it's content we have overflow thus the scroll. The body is not empty

Comment: add a border to container : https://jsfiddle.net/nky2buhr/10/ then resize and you will see when the scroll appear, it's exaclty when the container is bigger than the body

Comment: here is how you can do it : https://jsfiddle.net/nky2buhr/21/

Comment: Thanks, @TemaniAfif! That's a lot to absorb. I understand your point about overflow. When the content is taller than its container there's overflow, and so a vertical scrollbar appears. Now it's time to understand your working example!

Comment: the trick of the example is that I used `max-height:100%` on the container and the right element to limit their height to parent height and avoid a scroll to appear. Considering this the right element will shrink BUT it's content inside is having a fixed height so this height will be taller and we create the overflow

Comment: @TemaniAfif Interesting. Thanks for explaining the trick.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Your solution worked on my site. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: @TemaniAfif, put it in an answer!